# gotchas where Numpy differs from straight python?

Tags: python, numpy

Folks,

is there a collection of gotchas where Numpy differs from python,
points that have puzzled and cost time ?

> "The horror of that moment I shall
>   never never forget !"
>   "You will, though," the Queen said, "if you don't
>   make a memorandum of it."

For example, NaNs are always trouble, anywhere.
If you can explain this without running it, give yourself a point --

```
from numpy import array, NaN, isnan

pynan = float("nan")
print pynan is pynan, pynan is NaN, NaN is NaN
a = (0, pynan)
print a, a[1] is pynan, any([aa is pynan for aa in a])

a = array(( 0, NaN ))
print a, a[1] is NaN, isnan( a[1] )
```

(I'm not knocking numpy, lots of good work there, just think a FAQ or Wiki of gotchas would be useful.)

Edit: I was hoping to collect half a dozen gotchas (surprises for people learning Numpy).
Then, if there are common gotchas or, better, common explanations,
we could talk about adding them to a community Wiki (where ?)
It doesn't look like we have enough so far.

Comment: should be community wiki

Comment: No one mentioned primitive types. Does this mean a python float is equivalent to a np.float and so on?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The biggest gotcha for me was that almost every standard operator is overloaded to distribute across the array.

Define a list and an array

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array(l)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Multiplication duplicates the python list, but distributes over the numpy array

```
>>> l * 2
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a * 2
array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
```

Addition and division are not defined on python lists

```
>>> l + 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
>>> a + 2
array([ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
>>> l / 2.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'
>>> a / 2.0
array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5])
```

Numpy overloads to treat lists like arrays sometimes

```
>>> a + a
array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
>>> a + l
array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
```

Comment: Yes, that got me too. A simple table with columns: op, python, numpy
would settle that.

Comment: Actually ``a + a`` **is** defined for lists. It concatenates them.

Answer (score 25):

Because `__eq__` does not return a bool, using numpy arrays in any kind of containers prevents equality testing without a container-specific work around.

Example:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array(range(3))
>>> b = numpy.array(range(3))
>>> a == b
array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> x = (a, 'banana')
>>> y = (b, 'banana')
>>> x == y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This is a horrible problem.  For example, you cannot write unittests for containers which use `TestCase.assertEqual()` and must instead write custom comparison functions.  Suppose we write a work-around function `special_eq_for_numpy_and_tuples`.  Now we can do this in a unittest:

```
x = (array1, 'deserialized')
y = (array2, 'deserialized')
self.failUnless( special_eq_for_numpy_and_tuples(x, y) )
```

Now we must do this for every container type we might use to store numpy arrays.  Furthermore, `__eq__` might return a bool rather than an array of bools:

```
>>> a = numpy.array(range(3))
>>> b = numpy.array(range(5))
>>> a == b
False
```

Now each of our container-specific equality comparison functions must also handle that special case.

Maybe we can patch over this wart with a subclass?

```
>>> class SaneEqualityArray (numpy.ndarray):
...   def __eq__(self, other):
...     return isinstance(other, SaneEqualityArray) and self.shape == other.shape and (numpy.ndarray.__eq__(self, other)).all()
... 
>>> a = SaneEqualityArray( (2, 3) )
>>> a.fill(7)
>>> b = SaneEqualityArray( (2, 3) )
>>> b.fill(7)
>>> a == b
True
>>> x = (a, 'banana')
>>> y = (b, 'banana')
>>> x == y
True
>>> c = SaneEqualityArray( (7, 7) )
>>> c.fill(7)
>>> a == c
False
```

That seems to do the right thing.  The class should also explicitly export elementwise comparison, since that is often useful.

Answer (score 22):

I think this one is funny:

```
>>> import numpy as n
>>> a = n.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> a[1], a[0] = a[0], a[1]
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

For Python lists on the other hand this works as intended:

```
>>> b = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> b[1], b[0] = b[0], b[1]
>>> b
[[3, 4], [1, 2]]
```

Funny side note: numpy itself had a bug in the `shuffle` function, because it used that notation :-) (see [here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2006-November/024783.html)).

The reason is that in the first case we are dealing with *views* of the array, so the values are overwritten in-place.

Comment: Could you explain how the numpy array ends up being so?

Answer (score 12):

`NaN` is not a singleton like `None`, so you can't really use the is check on it. What makes it a bit tricky is that `NaN == NaN` is `False` as IEEE-754 requires. That's why you need to use the `numpy.isnan()` function to check if a float is not a number. Or the standard library `math.isnan()` if you're using Python 2.6+.

Comment: Well it's in the definition of NaN. def isnan(x): return (x != x)

Answer (score 7):

Slicing creates views, not copies.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> s = l[2:3]
>>> s[0] = 5
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> a = array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> s = a[2:3]
>>> s[0] = 5
>>> a
array([1, 2, 5, 4])
```

Comment: not always:
"There are two kinds of fancy indexing in numpy, which behave
similarly ..."
http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2008-January/031101.html

Answer (score 6):

The truth value of a Numpy array differs from that of a python sequence type, where any non-empty sequence is true.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = [0,1,2,3]
>>> a = np.arange(4)
>>> if l: print "Im true"
... 
Im true
>>> if a: print "Im true"
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use
a.any() or a.all()
>>>
```

The numerical types are true when they are non-zero and as a collection of numbers, the numpy array inherits this definition. But with a collection of numbers, truth could reasonably mean "all elements are non-zero" or "at least one element is non-zero". Numpy refuses to guess which definition is meant and raises the above exception. Using the `.any()` and `.all()` methods allows one to specify which meaning of true is meant.

```
>>> if a.any(): print "Im true"
... 
Im true
>>> if a.all(): print "Im true"
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
In [1]: bool([])
Out[1]: False

In [2]: bool(array([]))
Out[2]: False

In [3]: bool([0])
Out[3]: True

In [4]: bool(array([0]))
Out[4]: False
```

So don't test for the emptiness of an array by checking its truth value.  Use `size(array())`.

And don't use `len(array())`, either:

```
In [1]: size(array([]))
Out[1]: 0

In [2]: len(array([]))
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: size(array([0]))
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: len(array([0]))
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: size(array(0))
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: len(array(0))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5b2872696128> in <module>()
----> 1 len(array(0))

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Comment: You suggest to use `size(array(.))`, so how about using `len(array(.))`?

Comment: No, `len` is different from `size`. `size(array(0))` → 1 because a 0-rank array has one value in it, while `len(array(0))` raises an exception `len() of unsized object`

Comment: Looks like another gotcha then. What is the reasoning why `array(0)` should be a valid construct?

Answer (score 5):

(Related, but a NumPy vs. SciPy gotcha, rather than NumPy vs Python)

---

Slicing beyond an array's real size works differently:

```
>>> import numpy, scipy.sparse

>>> m = numpy.random.rand(2, 5) # create a 2x5 dense matrix
>>> print m[:3, :] # works like list slicing in Python: clips to real size
[[ 0.12245393  0.20642799  0.98128601  0.06102106  0.74091038]
[ 0.0527411   0.9131837   0.6475907   0.27900378  0.22396443]]

>>> s = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix(m) # same for csr_matrix and other sparse formats
>>> print s[:3, :] # doesn't clip!
IndexError: row index out of bounds
```

So when slicing `scipy.sparse` arrays, you must make manually sure your slice bounds are within range. This differs from how both NumPy and plain Python work.

Answer (score 3):

```
print pynan is pynan, pynan is NaN, NaN is NaN
```

This tests identity, that is if it is the same object. The result should therefore obviously be True, False, True, because when you do float(whatever) you are creating a new float object.

```
a = (0, pynan)
print a, a[1] is pynan, any([aa is pynan for aa in a])
```

I don't know what it is that you find surprising with this.

```
a = array(( 0, NaN ))
print a, a[1] is NaN, isnan( a[1] )
```

This I did have to run. :-) When you stick NaN into an array it's converted into a numpy.float64 object, which is why a[1] is NaN fails.

This all seems fairly unsurprising to me. But then I don't really know anything much about NumPy. :-)

Answer (score 3):

No one seems to have mentioned this so far:

```
>>> all(False for i in range(3))
False
>>> from numpy import all
>>> all(False for i in range(3))
True
>>> any(False for i in range(3))
False
>>> from numpy import any
>>> any(False for i in range(3))
True
```

numpy's `any` and `all` don't play nicely with generators, and don't raise any error warning you that they don't.

Answer (score 2):

from Neil Martinsen-Burrell in [numpy-discussion](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2009-September/045041.html) 7 Sept  --

> The ndarray type available in Numpy is
>   not conceptually an extension of 
>   Python's iterables.  If you'd like to
>   help other Numpy users with this 
>   issue, you can edit the documentation
>   in the online documentation editor  at
>   [numpy-docs](http://docs.scipy.org/numpy/docs/numpy-docs/user/index.rst)

Answer (score 2):

I found the fact that multiplying up lists of elements just creates view of elements caught me out.

```
>>> a=[0]*5
>>>a
[0,0,0,0,0]
>>>a[2] = 1
>>>a
[0,0,1,0,0]
>>>b = [np.ones(3)]*5
>>>b
[array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])]
>>>b[2][1] = 2
>>>b
[array([ 1.,  2.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  2.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  2.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  2.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  2.,  1.])]
```

So if you create a list of elements like this and intend to do different operations on them you are scuppered ...

A straightforward solution is to iteratively create each of the arrays (using a 'for loop' or list comprehension) or use a higher dimensional array (where e.g. each of these 1D arrays is a row in your 2D array, which is generally faster).

Comment: This looks like a pure python gotcha, entirely unrelated to `numpy`.

Comment: jolvi ... look a little closer ... try this with range(3) instead of np.ones(3) ... that's the subtlety by which is is a numpy gotcha. its an intentional behavior as it generally makes code faster and can be worked around.

Comment: `[range(3)] * 5` evaluates to `[range(0, 3), range(0, 3), range(0, 3), range(0, 3), range(0, 3)]`. If I do `a = [list(range(3))] * 5; a[0][0] = 33` I see exactly the same as in the `numpy` case: 5 references to one single `list` instance with first element set to `33`, like the one single `numpy.array` instance as you did.

Comment: The `operation [whatever] * 5` is, AFAICS, entirely unrelated to `whatever` is, and entirely unrelated to `numpy`. It produces 5 references to the very same object. If you change the object you will see the change in all `5` references.

Answer (score 2):

Not such a big gotcha: With boolean slicing, I sometimes wish I could do

```
  x[ 3 <= y < 7 ]
```

like the python double comparison.   Instead, I have to write

```
  x[ np.logical_and(3<=y, y<7) ]
```

(Unless you know something better?)

Also, np.logical_and and np.logical_or only take two arguments each, I would like them to take a variable number, or a list, so I could feed in more than just two logical clauses.

(numpy 1.3, maybe this has all changed in later versions.)

Comment: What about

    x[(3<=y) & (y<7)]

?

Answer (score 2):

A surprise with the `*=` assignment in combination with `numpy.array`:

```
>>> from numpy import array

>>> a = array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a *= 1.1  
>>> print(a) 
[1 2 3]  # not quite what we expect or would like to see

>>> print(a.dtype)
int64  # and this is why

>>> a = 1.1 * a  # here, a new array is created
>>> print(a, a.dtype)
[ 1.1  2.2  3.3] float64  # with the expected outcome
```

Surprising, annoying, but understandable. The `*=` operator will not change the type of the `array` data, thereby multiplication of an `int` `array` by a `float` will fail in the conventional meaning of this multiplication. The Python version `a = 1; a *= 1.1` in the other hand works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

A 0-d array of None looks like None but it is not the same:

```
In [1]: print None
None

In [2]: import numpy

In [3]: print numpy.array(None)
None

In [4]: numpy.array(None) is None
Out[4]: False

In [5]: numpy.array(None) == None
Out[5]: False

In [6]: print repr(numpy.array(None))
array(None, dtype=object)
```