# NaN in python and validity checking

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I'm doing a program where I optimize some values. Due to the equations, from time to time my values are NaN

My problem, some of the entries are NaN.

I would like to know if there is a test to check their logical validity so I can skip those values and retry.

So far I have tried checking for

```
a==np.nan, a==nan, b=a a==b
```

To no avail.

I hope you can help me

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using numpy,

```
import numpy as np
np.isnan(np.nan) # returns True
```

Answer (score 7):

Since Python 2.6, you want to `import math` and use `math.isnan(a)`.

See http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.isnan

Comment: Any reason why one would want to use `math` instead of `numpy`?

Comment: Actually, I may have found [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322380/gotchas-where-numpy-differs-from-straight-python) to my own question :)