# Numpy: need a hand in understanding what happens with the "in" operator

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with this (and explaining what's going on).

This works:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> a = array((2, 1))
>>> b = array((3, 3))
>>> l = [a, b]
>>> a in l
True
```

But this does not:

```
>>> c = array((2, 1))
>>> c in l
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The behaviour I would like to replicate is:

```
>>> x = (2, 1)
>>> y = (3, 3)
>>> l2 = [x, y]
>>> z = (2, 1)
>>> z in l2
True
```

Note that what above also work with mutable objects:

```
>>> x = [2, 1]
>>> y = [3, 3]
>>> l2 = [x, y]
>>> z = [2, 1]
>>> z in l2
True
```

Of course, knowing that:

```
>>> (a < b).all()
True
```

I tried (and failed):

```
>>> (c in l).all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python makes the choice that `bool([False,True])` is `True` because (it says) any non-empy list has boolean value True.

Numpy makes the choice that `bool(np.array([False, True]))` should raise a ValueError. Numpy was designed from the point of view that some users may want to know if **any** of the elements in the array are True, while others may want to know if **all** the elements in the array are True. Since the users may have conflicting desires, NumPy refuses to guess. It raises a ValueError and suggests using `np.any` or `np.all` (though if one wishes to replicate Python-like behavior, you'd use `len`).

When you evaluate `c in l`, Python compares `c` with each element in `l` starting with `a`. It evaluates `bool(c==a)`. We get `bool(np.array([True True]))`, which raises a ValueError (for the reason described above).

Since numpy refuses to guess, you have to be specific. I suggest:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array((2,1))
b=np.array((3,3))
c=np.array((2,1))
l=[a,b]
print(any(np.all(c==elt) for elt in l))
# True
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you (+1)... I am still not getting why `a in l` gets a different result than `c in l` though. In both cases the command should test a numpy array in a standard list... what is the difference I can't see?

Comment: @mac: That is a great question, and I don't know the answer. [The docs say](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin), "For the list and tuple types, x in y is true if and only if there exists an index i such that x == y[i] is true.", but `bool(a==l[0])` raises a ValueError and yet `a in l` returns True. I don't know how to resolve this (seeming) contradiction.

Comment: `list.__contains__()` checks for identity first, then equality. So `a in [a,b]` returns True only because the first item is `a`. Anything else, even a different array object that happens to have all of the same values of `a` will evaluate the equality comparison, get an array, and then get an exception when it tries to cast that array to a bool.

Comment: @RobertKern: [Oh, I see](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/d27f95e3b52f)... Thanks very much for the explanation.

Comment: @RobertKern thank you. That clarifies. I also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322380/gotchas-where-numpy-differs-from-straight-python/6065203#6065203) to be interesting, although not the answer I was looking for. I'm selecting the answer as accepted now: you share the moral glory for that though! :)