# Numpy: checking if an element in a multidimensional array is in a tuple

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

It seems I still struggle with [the "in" operator in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989676/numpy-need-a-hand-in-understanding-what-happens-with-the-in-operator/7989956#7989956). Here's the situation:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(1, 10, (2, 2, 3))
>>> a
array([[[9, 8, 8],
        [4, 9, 1]],

       [[6, 6, 3],
        [9, 3, 5]]])
```

I would like to get the indexes of those triplets whose second element is in `(6, 8)`. The way I intuitively tried is:

```
>>> a[:, :, 1] in (6, 8)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element...
```

**My ultimate goal would be to insert at those positions the the number preceding those multiplied by two.** Using the example above, `a` should become:

```
array([[[9, 18, 8],   #8 @ pos #2 --> replaced by 9 @ pos #1 by 2
        [4, 9, 1]],

       [[6, 12, 3],   #6 @ pos #2 --> replaced by 6 @ pos #1 by 2
        [9, 3, 5]]])
```

Thank you in advance for your advice and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[9, 8, 8],
               [4, 9, 1]],

              [[6, 6, 3],
               [9, 3, 5]]])

ind=(a[:,:,1]<=8) & (a[:,:,1]>=6)
a[ind,1]=a[ind,0]*2
print(a)
```

yields

```
[[[ 9 18  8]
  [ 4  9  1]]

 [[ 6 12  3]
  [ 9  3  5]]]
```

---

If you wish to check for membership in a set which is not a simple range, then I like both [mac's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024305/numpy-checking-if-an-element-in-a-multidimensional-array-is-in-a-tuple/8024538#8024538) of using a Python loop and [bellamyj's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024305/numpy-checking-if-an-element-in-a-multidimensional-array-is-in-a-tuple/8024510#8024510) of using np.in1d. Which is faster depends on the size of `check_tuple`:

**test.py:**

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

N = 10
a = np.random.randint(1, 1000, (2, 2, 3))
check_tuple = np.random.randint(1, 1000, N)

def using_in1d(a):
    idx = np.in1d(a[:,:,1], check_tuple)
    idx=idx.reshape(a[:,:,1].shape)
    a[idx,1] = a[idx,0] * 2
    return a

def using_in(a):
    idx = np.zeros(a[:,:,0].shape,dtype=bool)
    for n in check_tuple:
        idx |= a[:,:,1]==n
    a[idx,1] = a[idx,0]*2
    return a

assert np.allclose(using_in1d(a),using_in(a))
```

When N = 10, `using_in` is slightly faster:

```
% python -m timeit -s'import test' 'test.using_in1d(test.a)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 156 usec per loop
% python -m timeit -s'import test' 'test.using_in(test.a)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 143 usec per loop
```

When N = 100, `using_in1d` is much faster:

```
% python -m timeit -s'import test' 'test.using_in1d(test.a)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 171 usec per loop
% python -m timeit -s'import test' 'test.using_in(test.a)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 msec per loop
```

Comment: Is there a badge for the Official numpy-tutoring? If it were you would have got it. :) Do you have any pointer to some good study material on numpy? The official [tentative] tutorial and the reference material is structured in a way for which I find it difficult to find the info I need... :-/

Comment: BTW: this is a neat workaround, but if it were possible to use the `in` operator would have preferred, as in my "real case" I have a pool of roughly 10 values, non only `(6, 8)`.

Comment: The trick is not in what you read, but how you read it. For each function, spend a few minutes asking, what is a simple example that
demonstrates how this function behaves? When might I use this?  Start building
an examples file that exercises/demonstrates each function/concept. Learning comes as a side-effect of building the examples file.

The tentative tutorial and official docs are great resources.  You might also
try holing up some weekend with the [numpy book](http://www.tramy.us/) and
[user guide](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/numpy-user.pdf).
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that will work for an arbitrary length tuple.  It uses the `numpy.in1d` function.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

a = np.random.randint(1, 10, (2, 2, 3))
print(a)

check_tuple = (6, 9, 1)

bool_array = np.in1d(a[:,:,1], check_tuple)
ind = np.where(bool_array)[0]
a0 = a[:,:,0].reshape((len(bool_array), ))
a1 = a[:,:,1].reshape((len(bool_array), ))
a1[ind] = a0[ind] * 2

print(a)
```

And the output:

```
[[[6 9 6]
  [1 1 2]]

 [[8 7 3]
  [5 6 3]]]

[[[ 6 12  6]
  [ 1  2  2]]

 [[ 8  7  3]
  [ 5 10  3]]]
```

Comment: Interesting to discover the use of `in1d`. It's a bit verbose (in terms of number of operation transformed) but worth experimenting with it! +1

Answer (score 1):

There is another method based on using a lookup table which I learned from one of the developers of Cellprofiler.
First you need to create a lookup-table (LUT) which has the size of the largest number in your array. For each possible array value, the LUT has either a True or a false value. 
Example:

```
# create a large volume image with random numbers
a = np.random.randint(1, 1000, (50, 1000 , 1000))
labels_to_find=np.unique(np.random.randint(1,1000,500))

# create filter mask LUT 
def find_mask_LUT(inputarr, obs):
    keep = np.zeros(np.max(inputarr)+1, bool)
    keep[np.array(obs)] = True
    return keep[inputarr]

# This will return a mask that is the 
# same shape as a, with True is a is one of the 
# labels we look for, False otherwise
find_mask_LUT(a, labels_to_find)
```

This works really fast (much faster than np.in1d, and the speed does not depend on the number of objects.)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [*unutbu*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024305/numpy-checking-if-an-element-in-a-multidimensional-array-is-in-a-tuple/8024355#8024355) I found out this possible solution:

```
>>> l = (8, 6)
>>> idx = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=bool)
>>> for n in l:
...     idx |= a[:,:,1] == n
>>> idx
array([[ True, False],
       [ True, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> a[idx]
array([[9, 8, 8],
       [6, 6, 3]])
```

It requires to know the dimensions of the array to investigate beforehand, though.