# Why does python return True for this statement with numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I naively used a test with this structure, thinking that it was actually checking if a vector is contained in a matrix:

```
np.array([1,0]) in np.identity(2) #True
```

But then I discovered that also this is True:

```
np.array([1,1]) in np.identity(2) #True
```

Why is python returning True? What is actually being checked? I probably don't understand what `in` does (and it's hard to google, because "in" is interpreted as a regular preposition)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989676/numpy-need-a-hand-in-understanding-what-happens-with-the-in-operator) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452843/in-operator-for-numpy-arrays)

Comment: Looks like `in` checks if _any_ element on the right is in the array on the left. I could not find any documented evidence.