# Funny behavior of operator overloading in Python numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy

Say I have a python array and a numpy array

```
import numpy as np
python_array = [range(20), range(20), range(20)] 
numpy_array = np.array(python_array)
```

You can do:

```
numpy_array + python_array
```

However, this gives the same result:

```
python_array + numpy_array
```

while `__add__` of a python array is just concatenation. In fact, if you do:

```
python_array.\__add__(numpy_array)
```

it gives:

```
 can only concatenate list (not "numpy.ndarray") to list
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Could be what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/1324939/5110035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also an [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) method for `b` to implement `a + b` if `a` doesn't understand the operation. You're seeing `numpy.ndarray.__radd__`.

Comment: This is what I suspect but I didn't know there is a ``__radd__``. Thanks